What are some good libraries for information processing task queueing that provide a dashboard?
I want a kind of "information retrieval dashboard" or "data processing dashboard". I want to create something where I can input URLs to websites, and then it crawls them, extracts the main text, does some natural language processing in the text and saves everything in a database. I want all of this to have a web dashboard where I can: (1) see the status of each document, (2) what task it is doing at the moment, and (3) see and explore the "results" (filter documents by tags, etc.).
Is there any library that facilitates all this or do I have make my own from zero using a database and flask?
